# Strange Router URI Matching in Laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

```
Route::get('get/{user_id}-{name?}', function($user_id, $name) {
    // Do something
}
```

Why does `Route::get('get/{user_id}-{name?}')` matches `get/1234`? What happened to the dash `-` before `{name?}`, how did it became optional?

*Side question: Is it true that the name in the braces (eg: `name` in `{name}`) can be anything and not necessary the name of the parameter being passed into the route's callback function?*

Comment: That's because you have the optional last parameter and `-` is one of separators that being optional in front of optional parameters. So regex is something like `^get/(?P<user_id>[^/\-]++)(-(?P<name>[^/]++))?$`

Comment: Side question answer: that's correct. The placeholder is their for when you want to use restrictions, e.g., `Route::get('get/{user_id}', function($id){ })->where('user_id', '\d+');` This would ensure that the `{user_id}` segment is only digits.